# Pure CSS way to make progress bar at bottom of div?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a pure CSS version of this mockup below.

[image]

Ideally,

- the width would be constant no matter the name inside (15 char max),
- the icon panel on the right would always be there,
- but the icons themselves can be visible/invisible and maintain their positioning

That's not really working, but my biggest jape is with the exp bar on the bottom. Is there a pure css way to make that dynamic? I'm guessing two divs, one would be 100% width and the other would be on top with whatever % is necessary.

Here's what I was able to do so far:

```css
.sprite {
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.exp, .info, .pkmn_special {
  display: inline-block;
}

.pkmn_special {
  background-color: rgba(142,109,146,0.55);
}

.info {
  width: 230px;
  background: linear-gradient(15deg,#745fb5,#9a6dbb);
  background: #745fb5;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(102,119,136,0.55);
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(51,68,85,0.3);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-bottom: solid 5px grey;
}

.pkmn_name {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
<img class="sprite" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/e/ea/113MS.png" />
<code class="pkmn_name">15Characterssss</code>
  <div class="pkmn_special">
    <img src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/c/c5/Leaf_Crown_Sprite.png" />
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/kB8vi6/heart.png">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/e7w4bR/Shiny_VIStar.png">
  </div>
  <div class="exp"> </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, it looks pretty awful.
Would anyone be able to help me? Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: The biggest issue is trying to make the green exp bar in the exact same spot as the grey bar on the bottom. The closest I've got is a bar that is just above it - I'm wondering if there is a pure css way to do it

Comment: Make the small (green) div inside the bigger one and make it `position: absolute;` and `width: percentage;`

Comment: Here's a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qjhz4hbr/) example where the progress bar has been created using two divs and a lot of the other design elements have been solved through a combination of `position: relative` and `position: absolute`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `pseudoelement`.

Update the `width` as you need.

If you change the border-width of `.info` you will need to adjust both `height` and `bottom` position of the `pseudoelement`.

Also keep track of the `border-radius`. You can set specific corners to round on the `pseudoelement` to match the container.

```css
.sprite {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.exp,
.info,
.pkmn_special {
  display: inline-block;
}

.pkmn_special {
  background-color: rgba(142, 109, 146, 0.55);
}

.info {
  width: 230px;
  background: linear-gradient(15deg, #745fb5, #9a6dbb);
  background: #745fb5;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(102, 119, 136, 0.55);
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(51, 68, 85, 0.3);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-bottom: solid 5px grey;
  position: relative;
  
}

.info:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: green;
  width: 60%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}

.pkmn_name {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <img class="sprite" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/e/ea/113MS.png" />
  <code class="pkmn_name">15Characterssss</code>
  <div class="pkmn_special">
    <img src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/c/c5/Leaf_Crown_Sprite.png" />
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/kB8vi6/heart.png">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/e7w4bR/Shiny_VIStar.png">
  </div>
  <div class="exp"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you - I never really grasped pseudoelements, but I think I can get the rest to work :) !

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with pseudoelements, then you can just add an ´<div>´ inside ´<div class="exp"> </div>´ and style that like the pseudo-element. That is essentially the same (here)

Answer (score -2):

```
.sprite {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.exp,
.info,
.pkmn_special {
  display: inline-block;
}

.pkmn_special {
  background-color: rgba(142, 109, 146, 0.55);
}    
.info {
  width: 230px;
  background: linear-gradient(15deg, #745fb5, #9a6dbb);
  background: #745fb5;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(102, 119, 136, 0.55);
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(51, 68, 85, 0.3);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-bottom: solid 5px grey;
  position: relative;      
}

.info:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: green;
  width: 60%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}

.pkmn_name {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

Comment: Please don't just post code, but explain what you did and why it works